# Проблемы с глубиной OpenGL 4.0 - задние текстуры рисуются поверх передних

Tags: c++, opengl

Задние текстуры рисуются поверх передних:

[image]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#include "shader.h"
#include "stb_image.h"

#define speed 0.002f * time


int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(640, 640), L"Window", sf::Style::Default);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    sf::Clock clock;
    float time;
    glewInit();
    
    Shader shader("vertexShader.vert", "fragmentShader.frag");
    
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("grass.png", &width, &height, &channels, 0);
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
     
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    
    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    
    
    glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 16, 16, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    
    glm::mat4 trans(1.0f);
    trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(55.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    trans = glm::scale(trans, glm::vec3(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-55.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); 
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f));
    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    
    sf::Vector3f camera(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    
    GLint cameraPosition = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "cameraPos");
    GLuint modelPosition = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "model");
    GLuint viewPosition = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "view");
    GLuint projectionPosition = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "projection");
    
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            { 
                glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
                projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), event.size.width/(event.size.height * 1.0f), 0.1f, 100.0f);
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                {
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        {
            camera.x -= speed;
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        {
            camera.x += speed;
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        {
            camera.y -= speed;
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
        {
            camera.y += speed;
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
        {
            model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        }
        
        time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds() / 800.0;
        clock.restart();
//        std::cout << time << std::endl;
        
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        
        shader.use();
        glUniform3f(cameraPosition, camera.x, camera.y, camera.z);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelPosition, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewPosition, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionPosition, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        
        window.display();
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Шейдеры вершинный:

```
#version 400 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoords;

uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()                                  
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0) + vec4(cameraPos, 1.0);
    TexCoords = texCoords;
}
```

И фрагментный:

```
#version 400 core

out vec4 resultColor;
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main()
{
    resultColor = texture(Texture, TexCoords);
}
```

Код писал по уроку: https://ravesli.com/urok-8-sistemy-koordinat-v-opengl/

Comment: Попробуйте удалить glClearDepth(1.0f).

Comment: @NocteFury, и это я тоже уже пробовал - ничего.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема решена. Помогло

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 32;
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(640, 640), "Window", sf::Style::Default, settings);
```

Comment: Утро вечера мудренее. :D

Comment: @NocteFury, просто на другом форуме ответили быстрее)